# Error: "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'output' was corrupted." while using "MultiByteToWideChar" function

Tags: c++, c++17, codepages

I'm trying to create a function that will convert string into wstring.
I made a loop with the most fitting codepages (in my opinion), and then I started getting this error
I've had lots of issues with codepages, and spent a lot of time resolving Each of them, and I don't pretend to look like I really understand how to deal with them, but that is the idea I got about how to handle codepage conversion(cause I don't have any idea on how to determine which codepage I use, and how to change it to a preferred one, even after weeks googling it), but now I got this error, and I don't understand why it occurs and how to fix it

Any help with my code, codepages, and how to make this function better will be highly appreciated

```
namespace FurConHelper
{
    // to avoid adding #include <fcntl.h> header just for one value
    constexpr int _O_U16TEXT = 0x20000;
}

// converts string to wstring
std::wstring stringToWstring(const std::string& stringToConvert)
{   
    if (stringToConvert.empty()) 
        return wstring();
    static const vector<int32_t> codepages{ CP_UTF8, CP_ACP, CP_THREAD_ACP, CP_MACCP, CP_OEMCP, CP_UTF7, CP_SYMBOL }; //MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS    CP_UTF8 CP_UTF7 CP_THREAD_ACP CP_SYMBOL CP_OEMCP CP_MACCP CP_ACP
    uint32_t stringSize{};
    wstring output(stringSize + 1, 0);
    for (uint32_t index{}; index < codepages.size(); index++) // trying to find codepage needed to convert
    {
        stringSize = MultiByteToWideChar(codepages[index], MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, stringToConvert.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0);
        if (stringSize > 0) // if size is greater than 0 - everything shall be good, hopefully
        {
            if (MultiByteToWideChar(codepages[index], MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, stringToConvert.c_str(), -1, output.data(), stringSize) > 0)
            {
                return output; // at this point 'stringSize' becomes 2097271 somewhy. And the 'wstring output' becomes unreadable
            }
        }
    }
    stringSize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, NULL, stringToConvert.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0) ;
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, NULL, stringToConvert.c_str(), -1, output.data(), stringSize);
    return output;
} // at this point I get 'Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'output' was corrupted.' error

int main()
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(_setmode(_fileno(stdout), FurConHelper::_O_U16TEXT));                   
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(_setmode(_fileno(stdin), FurConHelper::_O_U16TEXT));                    
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(_setmode(_fileno(stderr), FurConHelper::_O_U16TEXT));                   
    if (!_wsetlocale(LC_ALL, L".utf8"))                                 
    {                                                                   
        wcout << L"setlocale invalid arg";  
    }                                                                   


    std::string wooffywoof{ "This string shall be converted без проблем :3 " };
    wcout << stringToWstring(wooffywoof);
    wcout << L"\nstill работает";

    
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for comments, and as Richard Critten, 1201ProgramAlarm and user4581301 said - I made a silly mistake with "output" variable. It was all fine, before I made a loop, and replaced "output" and "stringSize" above the first MultiByteToWideChar call. I just didn't notice that I broke the main logic of my function by this.

Thanks for pointing me into this mistake

Comment: Most likely the converted text is larger than the buffer space provided.

Comment: Set the required size of `output` from the return value from the 1st call to `MultiByteToWideChar`.  _"...if successful. If the function succeeds and cchWideChar is 0, the return value is the __required size, in characters__, for the buffer indicated by lpWideCharStr...."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar

Comment: Fundamentally, because `output` only has space for 1 character.

Comment: Also trying to use `MultiByteToWideChar` to guess the incoming (source) code-page is doomed.  The function assumes that you already know the code-page of the source string and will "blindly" do the best it can - garbage-in-garbage-out.

Comment: `uint32_t stringSize{};` -> `stringSize` = 0. `wstring output(stringSize + 1, 0);` string length  0 + 1. Don't think of C++ like a spreadsheet. It will not recompute anything after a variable is updated. If you want to `output` to have the size specified by the first call to `MultiByteToWideChar`, you'll have to size `output` **after** getting the correct size `stringSize = MultiByteToWideChar( ... );` currently happens too late to have any effect.

Comment: 1201ProgramAlarm
Oh.... Okay, that's silly, thanks for pointing me to such a silly mistake. It worked fine... Before I made a loop, and replaced it higher above the first function call... And I didn't notice that
Thank you

Comment: Richard Critten, yes, I know that it isn't a very bright idea! But I don't yet understand how to do it better. As soon as I will find it out, I'll change it to a better solution

Comment: @FurxyFluke other than knowing (the code-page) there isn't one.  There is too much (almost 100%) overlap in the code-page encodings.

Comment: @FurxyFluke normally you follow a documented fallback algorithm when you do this sort of thing. [HTML has a fairly detailed one](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#encodings) but falls back to a specific ISO-8859-1 Latin-1 if it can't figure  it out. It's on the developer to make sure they are transmitting it correctly. JSON requires UTF-8 for example...

Comment: @Mgetz, thank you for the link, will take a look at it! 
Everything about encoding tires me so much, guess that's the reason why I can't understand it well even spending weeks, or months on it

Comment: @FurxyFluke and that's why in general the answer should be `UTF-8` if MBCS or `UTF-16` otherwise. In general unless you're working in specific locales... that works wonders.

Comment: @Mgetz, yes, already found that out, but how to make everything work using only UTF-8 or UTF-16 - is still a bit of a mystery to me. Hopefully It will be easier for me soon